# How to connect 3 MPU9250 to Node Mcu together?

Tags: sensors, nodemcu, imu

I don't know how to connect 3 MPU9250 together on Node Mcu. There is not much information available. I am using bolder flight library for imu sensor - https://github.com/bolderflight/MPU9250

Can anyone post the image of connection on sensor and example of code? Thanks a lot.

Comment: it connects the same way as any other I2C device, so lookup an image of say, an oled or ads1115 adc or something like that.

Comment: but I want to do it 3 together?